# RavenDb proximity search

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I have an entity type:

```
public class Log
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And my Index:

```
public class LogIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Log>
{
    public LogIndex()
    {
        Map = xs => from x in xs
                    select new
                    {
                        x.Id,
                        x.Action,
                        x.Message 
                    };
    }
}
```

And then I store an entity`{ Action: "GetMessage", Message: "This is my Hello World message."}`.

Then I can get this entity by `Message:(Hello World)` or `Message:"Hello World"` on Raven Studio.

Now I want to `Proximity Search` this entity by `Message:(Hello World)~2`, I get an exception `unexpected tilde`.

Then I use `Message:"Hello World"~2`, I get nothing.
What should I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to support proximity search, you need to mark the `Message` as analyzed and use `Message:"Hello World"~2`